# Option "seal" in mount.cifs causes Ubuntu 20.04 client to crash

Tags: linux, freeze, cifs, seal

I'm running quite a few Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS clients here,
accessing a CIFS share on an OmniOS version r151046h ZFS server.
Authentication is done on a Windows 2019 PDC (which has suspended updates since end of last month).

Since Microsoft is forcing seal now, the mount command for the cifs share
was extended by the "seal" option in order to prepare the seal method.
It's now something like:

`sudo /sbin/mount.cifs //$HOST/data /netdrive -o seal, user=$USER,pass=$PASS,domain=$DOMAIN,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777`

But now the Linux clients freeze instantly as soon as files are copied and pasted using a filemanager.
I tried this with nautilus and Thunar.
The instant freeze happens as soon as the data is pasted.
No matter to which drive - local or remote.
No suspicious entries in the logs on the server or clients.

This ONLY happens using a filemanager!
A rsync of the same data has no problems at all.
Did an apt-upgrade on a U20 client, hoping there was a fix, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Lothar